# Trying to create a 1GB file with randomly generated numbers

Tags: python, csv, random

Created the following program in Python:

```
import csv
import os
from random import randint

with open('number.csv',"w") as f_out:
    f_write = csv.writer(f_out,delimiter=',')
    statinfo = os.stat('number.csv')
    file_size = statinfo.st_size
    x=[randint(0,99) for p in range(0,99)]

    for i in x:
        f_write.writerow(x)
```

The above program is not giving desired results; it writes the same line over and over and I don't know how to reach 1GB with this.

- Repetition of numbers is allowed.
- The file has to stop generating once the file size 
  reaches 1 GB.
- So I want random numbers (0,99), comma separated with series of lines with same number of
  columns in each line until the file size reaches 1 GB.

Comment: Please clarify: **1.** What is a 1GB file for you? **2.** Without repetition you can only create 100 numbers between 0 and 99, seems to be in conflict with my idea of 1GB. **3.** What is worrying about the end of the line?

Comment: It's also not clear what you mean by *worrying about end of the line* here. What is the output format you are trying to produce, do you need CSV output with a certain number of columns? And you repeatedly write the same row (you write it 99 times without generating new random values).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Repetition of numbers is allowed. With the program it is generating numbers randomly between 0 and 99 but once it generates 99 numbers randomly then the next line starts without any comma(,) and then the same random generated numbers are getting repeated in the next line. For ex: 67,88,0,3,5,6 .....9967,88,0,3,5,6 and so on. So if you notice there is no comma between 99 & 67 and the next line has same numbers as previous line. The file has to stop generating once the file size reaches 1 GB.

Comment: @Bujji: so you want numbers, comma separated, all on one line? Because you now generate lines with 99 numbers each, separated by commas, each line ending in a newline. There is no comma between 99 and 67 because there is a newline there instead.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Yes I want random numbers (0,99), comma separated with series of lines until the file size reaches 1 GB. So the numbers should generate like this: 67,88,0,3,5,6 .....99,78,4,8,0,1, and so on. The file should contain multiple lines (series of lines) not just single line.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to generate a *new* row each time, and check the file size after each row is written. You may as well use the `file.tell()` method to see where the file position is, once that goes beyond the 1GB line you have a big enough file:

```
import csv
from random import randint

per_row = 100  # number of columns per row to generate
target_size = 1024 ** 3  # 1 GiB, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte

with open('number.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
    f_write = csv.writer(f_out)

    while f_out.tell() < target_size:
        row = [randint(0, 99) for _ in range(per_row)]
        f_write.writerow(row)
```

I'm assuming that by 1GB you mean [1 Gibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte). You can replace the `1024 ** 3` value with `1000 ** 3` if you wanted the SI unit.

If all you wanted was one continuous stream of numbers (no line separators), write one number and then continuously write commas before the next number, until you hit the size. No need to use the `csv` module here then:

```
from random import choice

target_size = 1024 ** 3  # 1 GiB, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte
# convert to string just the once
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(100)]

with open('number.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(choice(numbers))
    while f_out.tell() < target_size:
        f_out.write(',{}'.format(choice(numbers)))
```

You could possibly get better performance by concatenating a bunch of numbers in larger blocks:

```
from random import choice

target_size = 1024 ** 3  # 1 GiB, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte
# convert to string just the once
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(100)]

with open('number.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(choice(numbers))
    while f_out.tell() < target_size:
        f_out.write(',')
        chunk = ','.join([choice(numbers) for _ in range(353)])
        f_out.write(chunk)
```

That gets you to 1GiB faster but may overshoot a little. The `353` number gives you *around* 1KiB of text (~35 1-character strings and ~318 two character strings, plus 353 commas == 1024 characters on average, given the distribution of the input numbers).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You need to include delimiter as comma(','). Yes it 1 gigabyte. Just executed the program and multiple line are generating with 100 columns each with line separater as space. Is there a way the next line also continues in the same line with comma separator without a space in between lines?

Comment: @Bujji: the delimiter is a comma *by default*, you don't need to specify it manually.

Comment: @Bujji: no spaces are generated in the file, lines are separated by `\r\n` (the CSV standard). Why do you want the line to start with a comma? This is why I asked you if you needed rows each on a line, or one long list of numbers comma-separated.

Comment: @Bujji: if you were to use, say, Excel to open the  file, you'll find it contains rows of 100 columns, each with random number in them, and then as many rows as it takes to generate 1GiB *at least*.

Comment: That's a big deviation from your original problem statement. Why are you using the `csv` module at all then?

Comment: Inorder to generate a comma separated file. Is there any other way to do it without csv module?

Comment: Sorry just executed the program. No the original problem statement is correct. Need multiple lines not single line but as I said earlier instead of lines separated by \r\n if the next line is also continued with comma separated instead of \r\n then it will fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense. Did you want `1,2,3\n,4,5,6\n,7,8,9`? So each line starts with another comma before continuing with more numbers? To get lines you *need* line separators. If you replace the line separators with commas you don't have lines anymore.

Comment: I want the file to look like this 1,2,3,....99,68,3,4,5....99 so 1,2,3,....99 is one line and 68,3,4,5....99 is another line etc.., there should not be \n in between the lines as a separator. So when I open the file it should show continuous numbers separated with commas, no gaps in between in the way of line separater \n. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Then you *don't have lines*. You have *one continuous line*, all numbers separated by commas. Just endlessly writing `,number` after the first number should achieve this.

Comment: @Bujji: this is a big deviation from your question, where you are writing CSV rows; CSV rows are separate lines (so separated by `\r\n`). You don't have any line separators, so there is only one line.

Comment: Lets say if it one line with continuous numbers separated by ','. How would you change the above program to achieve this output?

Comment: Thanks a lot it looks perfect.